if constexpr to initiallize a const reference
I have an expensive operation that I want to call conditionally depending on the template type.
The naive function looks basically like this.
template <typename T>
void FooNaive( const std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<T>>& vec )
{
    std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<float>> vecAsFloat;
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, float> )
        vecAsFloat = vec;   // expensive copy I want to avoid
    else
    {
        vecAsFloat.reserve( vec.size() );
        for ( const auto& s : vec )
            vecAsFloat.push_back( ConvertExpensiveStruct( s ) );   // <-- does not compile for floats
    }

    // ...use vecAsFloat...
}

In order to avoid the expensive copy of the first branch, I tried making vecAsFloat a const reference.  However, due to ConvertExpensiveStruct not compiling for float types (second branch), I still need an if constexpr in there.
This is my current attempt at it:
template <typename T>
void FooAttempt( const std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<T>>& vec )
{
    std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<float>> dummyVecAsFloat;
    if constexpr ( !std::is_same_v<T, float> )
    {
        dummyVecAsFloat.reserve( vec.size() );
        for ( const auto& s : vec )
            dummyVecAsFloat.push_back( ConvertExpensiveStruct( s ) );
    }
    const std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<float>>& vecAsFloat = std::is_same_v<T, float> ? vec : dummyVecAsFloat;

    // use vecAsFloat...
}

I also thought about putting the conversion loop in a lambda to be called in-place inside the ternary operator, but that would mean it would have to return a const reference to its local variable (extends lifetime, but still ugly), or at worse return a copy by value (do lambdas have NRVO?).
But it looks overly complicated. Is there a way to write this simpler, or at least with clearer intent?

You could just use views::transform.

Instead of mucking around with if constexpr, I'd consider partial template specialisation.   For example template<class T> void Foo(const std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<T>>& vec )  {  /* implementation for all non-specialised types */ }  followed by (a presumably small number of ) optimised partial specialisations such as template<> void Foo<float>(const std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<T>>& vec ) {/*  implementation to avoid expensive copy */}.

You can extract whatever you do at // use vecAsFloat... into a separate function, and then use if constexpr to create a temporary std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<float>> only if needed:
void FooAsFloat(const std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<float>>& vecAsFloat) {
    // use vecAsFloat...
}

template <typename T>
void Foo(const std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<T>>& vec)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>) {
        FooAsFloat(vec);  // no copy needed
    }
    else {
        std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<float>> vecAsFloat;
        vecAsFloat.reserve(vec.size());
        for (const auto& s : vec) {
            vecAsFloat.push_back(ConvertExpensiveStruct(s));
        }
        FooAsFloat(vecAsFloat); // call with copy
    }
}


As @Jarod42 commented below, you can even avoid the extration into another function:
Do the main processing in the if part, and use a recursive call for the else part after creating the needed std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<float>>:
template <typename T>
void Foo(const std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<T>>& vec)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, float>) {
        // use vec (it contains `ExpensiveStruct<float>` elements as needed) 
        // ...
    }
    else {
        std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<float>> vecAsFloat;
        vecAsFloat.reserve(vec.size());
        for (const auto& s : vec) {
            vecAsFloat.push_back(ConvertExpensiveStruct(s));
        }
        // Recursive call with `vecAsFloat`
        // (when executed it will get into the main `if constexpr` part to be used):
        Foo(vecAsFloat);
    }
}


Not even needed to extract into external method, "recursive" call might be done for the else part.

@Jarod42 thanks, that's an nice "trick" - added to my answer.

Thanks for accepting my answer @Blabba. Just in case you were not aware - you can also upvote any useful answer (including the accepted one) - as voting and accepting is separate. See: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

Simpler than you think:
template <typename T>
void FooAttempt( const std::vector<ExpensiveStruct<T>>& vec ) {
    auto const& vecAsFloat = [&vec]()
    ->decltype(auto)/*relax reference qualifications*/{
        if constexpr ( !std::is_same_v<T, float> ) /* return reference */
            return std::forward<decltype(vec)>(vec);
        else /* return value with direct  initialization. */
            return vec 
                 | std::views::transform 
                      ( [](auto&& s){return ConvertExpensiveStruct(s);} )
                 | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();
    }(/*vecAsFloat = IILE*/);

    /* use(data(vecAsFloat), size(vecAsFloat));
    ** use essentially an 'extern "C"' API, 
    ** OR a 3rd party binary library.*/
};

But if vecAsFloat need not be stored as a vector, and is only used(irerated) once, its even more efficient to drop the vector conversion and just keep a view:
template <typename T>
void FooAttempt( std::span<const ExpensiveStruct<T>> vec ) {
    auto const vecAsFloat = [vec]{
        if constexpr ( !std::is_same_v<T, float> )
            return vec;
        else
            return vec 
                 | std::views::transform 
                      ( [](auto&& s){return ConvertExpensiveStruct(s);} );
    }(/*vecAsFloat = IILE*/);

    /* Iterate over vecAsFloat, only once.
    ** 'use' is a user defined algorithm,
    ** expecting a range of `float` values */ 
};

Note the use of std::span in the second snippet. It's more generic in case you  decide to use a std::array instead of std::vector at call sight. It also reflects your intention not to insert or remove any elements.
